# Bluetooth service optimized, Android

Tags: android, bluetooth, bluetooth-lowenergy, battery-saver

I have an app that uses BLE to exchange data with a BLE-capable device.
I used to develop and test it using Asus Zenfone Max 3 (Android 8.1) and I had no problems.
Then, I got an Asus Zenfone Max Pro M1 (Android 8.1). The app connects to the device but could not exchange any data.
After long investigation, it turns out that I had to go to **Battery optimization** in the smartphone's settings and change **Bluetooth** and **Bluetooth MIDI Service** to *Not optimized* and then my app worked fine.
I don't know whether this default setting is related to the OS (Android One) or to the phone model. But it is really a crappy thing because I am not supposed to tell every customer to do this (in his phone's settings) in order for the app to work !
So, my question is, is their a way to know, from the code, whether these services are optimized or not, and whether I can change these settings by code or any other ideas that could better fix this issue.

Comment: I had the same problem with Bluetooth and notification when using Battery optimization for asus phone and it's about the OS and the user setting so I ended by showing a Dialog asking to disable it if any problem occurred

Comment: And how do you know that bluetooth is optimized in this case ? Can you test it by code ?

Answer (score 0):

Add this permission to your manifest file:

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS"/>
```

and test it like this :

```
Intent intent = new Intent();
String packageName = context.getPackageName();
PowerManager pm = (PowerManager) context.getSystemService(Context.POWER_SERVICE);
if (pm.isIgnoringBatteryOptimizations(packageName))
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATION_SETTINGS);
else {
    intent.setAction(Settings.ACTION_REQUEST_IGNORE_BATTERY_OPTIMIZATIONS);
    intent.setData(Uri.parse("package:" + packageName));
}
context.startActivity(intent);
```

[reference](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32424117/4063532)